# Xamarin forms ASP.NET android emulator cannot access localhost API

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm developing a Xamarin forms app that uses ASP.NET Web Application template. I [followed this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0v4srA4NhA&list=PLpbcUe4chE78YvgIMtmgNEmRGyGJcsQdF&index=5) on YouTube. I'm having problem using the PostAsync method. The web api itself can start OK via IIS Chrome on my local machine, but not via the emulator. I printed the response message, displayed as

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Date: Sun, 26 Sep 2021 06:53:22 GMT
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
  Content-Length: 334
}
```

Here's the service class which contains the RegisterAsync method

```
public class UserService
{

    private string androidApiUrl = "https://10.0.2.2:44358/api/Account/Register";
    private string iOSApiUrl = "https://localhost:44358/api/Account/Register";
    private HttpClient client;
  
    public UserService()
    {
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (msg, cert, chain, err) => { return true; };
        client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }
    public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(string username, string pswd, string confmPswd)
    {
        var newAccount = new ModelAccount
        {
            Email = username,
            Password = pswd,
            ConfirmPassword = confmPswd
        };

      
        
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newAccount);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);

        content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
        {
            CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName
        };

        try
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(androidApiUrl, content);
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the WebAPI's properties...
[image]

Here's the ModelConvert which is json-serialized.

```
class ModelAccount
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

If it makes any different if I changed the port number to 61902 as suggest by [this blog](https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3), it still won't work.

Thank you

Edit:
as requested by @Aristos, here are the port numbers connected.
[image]

Comment: I think tha the port is change evetimes the local iis starts - so check the port number on `localhost:44383`

Comment: How do you mean? Check the browser? Yes Chrome shows localhost:44358.

Comment: It's 44358 not 44383 as shown in my post @Aristos

Comment: do not check the browser, but the local server - usually you can find it on the small icons on taskbar

Comment: Hi I've included it in the Edit, please check.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works now that I've changed the url to http://10.0.2.2:55002/... But any ideas why the port number is different from the one I specified?

Comment: You are not define it there, there you just declare what to read. I am going to make it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the settings you have define the port number - usually this is a random port so probably have change on your system. Check on witch port your local iis is running when you run visual studio and change that according.

[image: settings]